# Differences of each version of TeXbook

Tags: books, learning, knuth

I'm going to buy The TeXbook, and I have two alternatives for that:

1. buy an old version one in a discounted price
2. buy the newest version one in the fixed price

To be honest, I would like to save money, but if there are fundamental differences between an old version of Texbook and the latest version of one, I think I should buy the latest version one even though there are some errata.

Here is  my question: is there any fundamental or big difference between an old version of Texbook and the latest version of TeXbook?

---

[EDIT] 19/9/2015

Now I understand that new feature of TeX3 is supported by the 17th printing of the softback version or the 11th printing edition of the hardcover version, or any later edition.

According to author's comment, there were two turning points for TeXbook after TeX3 was supported. Then  I would like to focus on those two things:

1. Is there any big difference between millennium printing edition and an earlier edition?
2. Is there any big difference between the 19th printing edition (from Apr. 2012) and  millennium edition?

Comment: how old is old? if it is TeX2 then don't get it (except for historical interest) as it has no information about language switching or anything else added at TeX3, if it is TeX3 (199-something) then all the changes are exceedingly minor and probably won't affect you)

Comment: You can see all the changes to D. Knuth's books here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/errata

Comment: Thanks for those comments. I got that there is a big difference between 80s TeXbook and 90s TeXbook. I would like to know such a big difference. I know those errata you mentioned and actually looked through them; however, it is difficult for me to point out which modification was important because I haven't read any TeXbook yet. Thus, I posted the question above.

Comment: TeX3 adds support for multiple languages `\language` and friends so if all your documents are in English that's interesting but not so important, in TeX2 you would have had to make a new format for other languages (and could not hyphenate any words with accented letters) latex has this setting for tex2 which gives an idea of what is new in tex3:  `\newcount\inputlineno\inputlineno-1 \newcount\language\newcount\lefthyphenmin\newcount\righthyphenmin\newcount\errorcontextlines\newcount\holdinginserts\newdimen\emergencystretch\newcount\badness\let\noboundary\relax\newcount\setlanguage`

Comment: Your question would be far more answerable if you stated which edition you have available second hand,

Comment: It is true indeed, but I don't have a way to confirm it for now. I'm going to buy it from Amazon.com (because I couldn't find out any TeXbook around me), and any merchant in there doesn't seem to mention about the edition they have. My plan was to ask about the differences of each edition in here, and then inquire with a merchant about the edition they have. It is rather a personal thing, so I avoided to include it in the question above.

Comment: as far as I can see you want at least the 17th printing of the softback version to have tex3.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you mind turning your comment into an answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue?

Comment: @erreka done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX3 adds support for multiple languages `\language` and friends so if all your documents are in English that's interesting but not so important, in TeX2 you would have had to make a new format for other languages (and could not hyphenate any words with accented letters) latex has this setting for TeX2 which gives an idea of what is new in TeX3:

```
\newcount\inputlineno
\inputlineno-1
\newcount\language
\newcount\lefthyphenmin
\newcount\righthyphenmin
\newcount\error‌​contextlines
\newcount\holdinginserts
\newdimen\emergencystretch
\newcount\badness
\let\noboundary\relax
\newcount\setlanguage
```

You want at least the 17th printing of the softback version to have TeX3.